# How to Select distinct data from three tables?

Tags: sql-server, join

How can I write a SQL statement to select distinct data from three tables?
There are three tables

1)

```
Registration 

      id  name contact

  123 abc  123456789
```

2) bookingReg

```
   PkBkID FkRegID ac_no 

   1       123     QT123
```

3) products

```
   PkPro FkBkID pro_name Qty price 

    1     1     abc      2   150

    2     1     def      1   400

    3     1     ghi      5   500

    4     1     abc      2   150

SELECT * FROM Registration as a

JOIN bookingReg as b ON (b.FkRegID = '123')

JOIN products as c ON (c.FkBkID = b.PkBkID )
```

I want distinct pro_name

Out put is

```
ac_no  qty price

QT123  8   1050
```

HOw ?

Comment: `b.FkRegID = '123'` does not qualify as a joining condition. It should be `b.FkRegID = a.id` I guess

Comment: qty and price are not corect output shown by you @jiten

Comment: This is for sure not your out putt. You are joining three tables and selecting all columns. Also, if you need to select `DISTINCT` pro_name why you are joining all the tables as you can referrer only the `products` table. And finally if you need `DISTINCT` values just use `DISTINCT` clause.

Comment: SELECT b.ac_no,SUM(c.qty)qty,sum(c.price)price  FROM Registration as a
    JOIN bookingReg as b ON (b.FkRegID = a.id)
    JOIN products as c ON (c.FkBkID = b.PkBkID ) 
    group by b.ac_no

Comment: @Jonathan calculate qty & price only distinct pro_name

Answer (score 0):

Answer based on my assumption

```
SELECT    pro_name, 
          ac_no, 
          SUM(qty) Sumqty, 
          SUM(price) SumPrice
FROM Registration a    
JOIN bookingReg b 
    ON b.FkRegID = a.id    
JOIN products c 
    ON c.FkBkID = b.PkBkID  
GROUP BY pro_name, ac_no
```

**EDIT** Remove `ac_no` from `SELECT` and `GROUP BY` if you don't want to see this field in result.

Comment: You do see a `SUM` and a `GROUP BY`, don't you?

Comment: @SoursevA I am using this query SELECT    pro_name, 
          ac_no, 
          SUM(qty) Sumqty, 
          SUM(price) SumPrice
FROM Registration a    
JOIN bookingReg b 
    ON b.FkRegID = '123'
JOIN products c 
    ON c.FkBkID = b.PkBkID  
GROUP BY pro_name, ac_no but error generate

Comment: I did not suggest this query

Answer (score 0):

Pls try this

```
SELECT A.ac_no, SUM(A.Qty) Qty, SUM(A.Price) Price
FROM 
(
SELECT DISTINCT B.ac_no, P.Qty, P.Price
FROM Registration R
INNER JOIN bookingReg B ON B.FkRegID  = R.id
INNER JOIN products P ON P.FkBkID = B.PkBkID
) A
GROUP BY A.ac_no
```

[image: Result-ScreenShot]

Comment: When i am using this query then error generate SELECT A.ac_no, SUM(A.Qty) Qty, SUM(A.Price) Price
FROM 
(
SELECT DISTINCT B.ac_no, P.Qty, P.Price
FROM Registration R
INNER JOIN bookingReg B ON B.FkRegID  = '123'
INNER JOIN products P ON P.FkBkID = B.PkBkID
) A
GROUP BY A.ac_no

Comment: this query working but sum of Qty & price are different that means not distinct output are 10,1200 actual out put are ac_no  qty price

QT123  8   1050

Comment: Desired output ac_no  qty price

QT123  8   1050 and query gives that result. Let me know if your desired result is not this.

Comment: If i use you query output is ac_no qty price QT123 10 1200 i need distinct pro_name actual output is ac_no qty price QT123 8 1050

Comment: Result screen shot is added above. Result is ac_no qty price QT123 8 1050

Comment: I need instinct pro_name sum of qty price not all

Comment: post complete details of desired result. What are the fields and corresponding data needed?